# Pagination in an API-Platform project with SQL-Server

Tags: sql-server, symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

I'm trying to create a REST API using [API Platform](https://api-platform.com/). My API use Doctrine to request data from an SQL Sever 2014 database. I have following the documentation to implement the default item collection request for my entity with server pagination.

When I try to request the first page of my list of items, the API return the first 30 line without problem. But when I try with another page the API return the following message:

> Platform mssql does not support offset values in limit queries

I found some posts saying that I have to write a custom cte SQL request but I would lose all the advantages of API-Platform's default item collection requests (like the use of ApiFilter per example).

I understand it's more a doctrine issue with SQL-Server than API-Platform. But is there a way to use API Platform core pagination with SQL Server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not found a clean solution to my problem but I manage to get the behaviour I wanted by using a custom Paginator class extending the Paginator class of Doctrine.